# How to pass Lambda output to a csv file and upload it to an AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have created a Lambda function to get the service list from each of our Accounts in our Organization. I wrote the below python code for this.

```
            import boto3

            from datetime import date, timedelta

            def lambda_handler(event, context):
            client2 = boto3.client('organizations')
            paginator = client2.get_paginator('list_accounts')
            page_iterator = paginator.paginate()
            for page in page_iterator:        
                for acct in page['Accounts']:
                    if acct['Status'] == 'ACTIVE':
                        acc_id = acct['Id']
                        print(str(acc_id))
                        sts_connection3 = boto3.client('sts')
                        acct_b3 = sts_connection3.assume_role(
                            RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::%s:role/OrganizationRole"%acc_id,
                            RoleSessionName='AssumeRoleSession2'
                        )
                        ACCESS_KEY = acct_b3['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
                        SECRET_KEY = acct_b3['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
                        SESSION_TOKEN = acct_b3['Credentials']['SessionToken']
                
                        client3= boto3.client(
                            'ce',
                            aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                            aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
                            aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
                        )
                        last_day_of_prev_month = date.today().replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
                        start_day_of_prev_month = date.today().replace(day=1) - 
                        timedelta(days=last_day_of_prev_month.day)
                        start_date = str(start_day_of_prev_month)
                        last_date = str(last_day_of_prev_month)
                        response = client3.get_cost_and_usage(
                            TimePeriod={
                                'Start': start_date,
                                'End': last_date
                            },
                            Granularity='MONTHLY',
                            Metrics=[
                                'AmortizedCost'
                            ],
                            GroupBy=[
                                {
                                    'Type': 'DIMENSION',
                                    'Key': 'SERVICE'
                                }
                            ]
                        )
                        service=[]
                        for item in response['ResultsByTime'][0]['Groups']:
                            service.append(
                                item['Keys'][0],
                            )
                        print(service)
```

Am getting an output like below,

988806687521

['AWS Backup', 'AWS CloudTrail', 'AWS Config', 'AWS Direct Connect', 'AWS Directory Service', 'AWS Key Management Service', 'AWS Lambda', 'AWS Secrets Manager', 'AWS Security Hub', 'AWS Step Functions', 'AWS Systems Manager', 'Amazon DynamoDB', 'EC2 - Other', 'Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute']

142278318693

['AWS CloudShell', 'AWS CloudTrail', 'AWS Key Management Service', 'AWS Lambda', 'AWS Secrets Manager', 'AWS Security Hub', 'AWS Step Functions', 'Amazon API Gateway']

I need to put this output into a CSV file and upload it to the s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you write to a csv file in Python:
https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-write-csv-file/

So you would replace your print statements with the `write` methods.

Afterwards, you can use this to upload your files to an s3 bucket:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html

You would create a boto3 client for S3 and then use the `upload_file` method to put it into a bucket.

Comment: I have tried this method, It add the last Account number and the services used in that Account. I need to collect all the account number and services in a single csv sheet